# A short proof that the set of discontinuities of a regulated function is countable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity, alternative-proof

Does a short proof exist for the following theorem?

> The set of discontinuities of a [regulated function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulated_function) on $[a, b]$ is countable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f$ be a regulated function, and by the definition there are a sequence of step functions $f_n$ converging uniformly to $f$. Let $D_n$ for any $n$ be the set of discontinuities of $f_n$ and $D=\displaystyle\bigcup_n D_n$. If $x \notin D$, it follows that $f$ is continuous at $x$ (why?), and therefore the set of discontinuities of $f$ is included in $D$, which is a countable union of finite sets, since step functions have finitely many discontinuities. It follows that $D$ is countable.